# How to create dynamic response model for Swagger in Nest JS

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I created an API which is returning selected fields of user data.

User model:

```
@Exclude()
@Entity('users')
export class User extends Timestampable {
    @ApiProperty()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['create', 'profile'] })
    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['create'] })
    @Column()
    password: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['profile'] })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    firstName: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['profile'] })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    lastName: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['profile'] })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    paternalName: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['profile'] })
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    phone: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @Expose({ groups: ['profile'] })
    @Column({ nullable: true, type: 'enum', enum: UserGender })
    gender: UserGender;
}
```

Inside the controller, I just return:

```
return instanceToPlain(user, {
                groups: ['profile'],
            });
```

here will be returned only the fields of the user which have a profile group.

Everything working properly. But for swagger documentation I used:

```
{
        schema: {shows
            $ref: getSchemaPath(User),
        },
    }
```

and in the documentation, it shows all fields of the user.

**How can I show only fields from the particular group?**

One of the options create 2 different DTOs and use them but that solution in my opinion is not that good.

Comment: I found a solution with `PickType` and `OmitType` methods provided by NestJS (see documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types).